# django: render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a code line in my views.py:

```
return render_to_response('errorInsertingData', message='Save isnt complete')
```

and the templete `errorInsertingData.html` code:

```
<script>
    alert('{{ message }}');
</script>
```

Why do I get an error:

> render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'

my goal is to get the msg 'Save isnt complete' as a popup / msg box.

Answer (score 1):

`render_to_response` doesn't have a `message` argument.

What you want is to pass a context dictionary where `message` is a key.

Which would be:

```
return render_to_response('errorInsertingData', {"message":"Save isnt complete"})
```

Comment: it says invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

dont use `render_to_response()` anymore, it is "deprecated"

use:

```
return render(request, 'errorInsertingData.html', {'message':'Save isnot complete'}
```

by doing so, [Request Object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) is automatically in the context available

or if you just want to return a string, then use:

```
return HttpResponse('Save isnot complete')
```

Comment: the render almost works. it gives a popup but there is no msg there. its blank.

Comment: @aayushdagra it must be some js typo,

Comment: there is no js. jse the templete i gave....  took the idea from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240746/django-how-to-implement-alertpopup-message-after-complete-method-in-view

Comment: @aayushdagra `alert()` IS a js. ;) if you render to correct template and invoke the alert in correct place, then it should work